# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest to capture AngularJS XHR requests

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to write a Chrome extension and I need to capture XHR requests right at the start the request but also on completion. So far I understand I need to use:

- chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest and
- chrome.webRequest.onCompleted

Here's my manifest file:

```
{
 "name": "Koala",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "test",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "koala.png",
    "default_popup": "koala.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "background":{
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

The event listeners need to go in the background script. Here's extract from my background.js file:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){
  //message to context.js and koala.js
},{urls: ["<all_urls>"],types: ["xmlhttprequest"]},[]);

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
  //message to context.js and koala.js
},{urls: ["<all_urls>"],types: ["xmlhttprequest"]},[]);
```

I tried displaying the content of the details object via alert, console.log, messaging but it just seems that the event listeners never capture anything. I want this code to capture any kind of HTML fragment injection, not just AngularJS ones so I cannot rely on AngularJS events alone. Am I missing anything obvious?

Thanks,

Alban

Comment: For background scripts you should be able to see the console, but you need to launch the debugger from the chrome://extensions view by clicking your background script next to the inspect views label under your extension.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your comment. chrome.webRequest is undefined. I have checked by accessing the background page, the chrome object exists but there's no webRequest object.

Comment: I think I found the issue. My manifest file had permissions declared twice. When I removed the 2nd declaration my background page recognised the chrome.webRequest object.

Answer (score 1):

I see it. 
You have permissions defined your manifest.json twice. Remove the second permissions property with only activeTab and you should be in business.